# How to get albums' URIs in an automatic way - Spotify API

Tags: python, api, uri, spotify

Good morning. I created this morning a program in python which, giving in input the URI of an album, gives me back the list of the tracks present in that album (using the Spotify API).
Following I continued the program in order to download the features of the songs in that list.

Since I need to perform this operation for several albums, I then created a json file with all the URIs of all the albums I need and with a FOR cycle I extracted all the tracks for each album (and then I extracted the songs features).

The problem is: if I have to download the track list of for example 500 albums, how can I get the URIs of each album in an automatic way? It seems impossible to get each URI by hand.

Maybe there is a way to give in input the list of track names and, exploiting the API, receive as output directly the features of those songs? Or maybe there is a way of giving in input the list of the albums' names and receive as output the URIs?
Thank you.

I tried to start getting all the URIs by hand, but it's too slow and not very scalable (maybe one day I need to download the tracks of a thousand of albums..).

EDIT: -------------------------------------------------------
Here's the code.

[first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJqM.png)

[second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc4G9.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the Python program you mentioned?

Comment: @Ximzend I've just added the code

Comment: You should put the first two lines inside the `for x in albums:` loop, outside the loop. And I see you've written a bunch of unnecessary code. Also, [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: You can make a script that searches for albums and put the URIs inside a file. Then, another script can put the tracks of the albums with using the URIs inside a playlist you can download. You'll need the top 4 lines [from here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/master/#quick-start) instead of the client credentials. The scope should be `"playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public"`.

Comment: Note: You'll need the track **URIs**, because IDs are no longer supported by `playlist_add_items(playlist_id, items, position=None)`.

Comment: @Ximzend do you know how I can make the script that searches for albums and put the URIs inside a file?

Comment: `sp.search(q, limit=1, offset=0, type='album', market=None)` where **q** is the album you are searching for. You can write one big script and put the album URIs in a list. (I removed the ** around the first q)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that does what you want:

```
import requests
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import urllib3
from pprint import pprint
import json
import time

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
redirect_uri = ""
scope = "playlist-modify-private,playlist-modify-public"


market = "NL" # Two letter code of your country
dl_playlist_id = "spotify:playlist:a1b2c3d4e5f6"  # the playlist of albums you want to download
album_names_file = "albums.txt"

# Anti rate-limit code
session = requests.Session()
retry = urllib3.Retry(
    total=0,
    connect=None,
    read=0,
    allowed_methods=frozenset(["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]),
    status=0,
    backoff_factor=0.3,
    status_forcelist=(429, 500, 502, 503, 504),
    respect_retry_after_header=False,  # <---
)
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount("http://", adapter)
session.mount("https://", adapter)

# log-in code
sp = spotipy.Spotify(
    auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
        scope=scope,
        open_browser=False,
    ),
    requests_session=session,
)

# Album names to IDs
with open(album_names_file) as f:
    albums = f.readlines()

album_ids = []

for album in albums:
    found = sp.search(album, limit=1, offset=0, type="album", market=market)
    try:
        album_ids.append(found["albums"]["items"][0]["id"])
    except:
        print(f"{album} not found.")

# add album tracks to playlist
for id in album_ids:
    album_data = sp.album_tracks(album_id = id, limit=50, market=market)
    uris = []
    for item in album_data["items"]:
        uris.append(item["uri"])
    sp.playlist_add_items(dl_playlist_id, uris)

print("Done")
```

Note: albums.txt should be a plain text file with a list of albums, with each name bellow the other; not a json file. You also can add the artist name next to the album name.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question and wrote more code than needed.